# Graphics card won't fill screen

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, tv

I am currently using a GeForce GTX 650Ti with three monitors. Two of which I have hooked up via DVI and my TV which is hooked up via a Mini HDMI port (Goes into a receiver first and then the receiver to the TV). The card says that it can support a maximum of 4096x2160. The TV is a FULLHD TV but the graphics card won't fill the whole screen.

I'm not sure whether or not it is because it is through a Mini HDMI or if the TV is too large (40 inch) for it to handle, but it's sorta frustrating. I went through all the resolutions, but nothing was fitting or the picture just didn't look crisp.

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: did you try hooking the tv directly to the card?  And what do you mean by filling the screen?  Does in not go to the edge of the screen at the full resolution?

Comment: I have not, because I have audio coming through the HDMI as well, so that's why I have it going to the receiver. I can try to "jimmy-rig" it so I plug the computer into the TV with the HDMI and then have the audio signal going to the TV and then be sent from the TV down to the receiver somehow? Would that work? And what I mean is that the picture is either too large or too small (depending on what I set the resolution to be). It's never the right one. So I guess I worded the question wrong.

Comment: 4096x2160 is 4K if I am not mistaken.  It sounds like your TV isn't a 4k TV.  "FULLHD" isn't UHDV which is normally used to describe 4k TVs.

Comment: Right, that I am aware of, but even when I change the resolution to 1920x1080 it doesn't fit right.

Comment: You didnt answer the question, are the edges of the image not touching the edges of the tvs screen?  or just past the edge of the screen?

Comment: On the setting I have currently, passed. But if I put it on a different resolution, it obviously changes.

Comment: google oversacn and underscan and see if this is what you are describing

Answer (score 0):

I know that I needed to increase the scaling to get "Full Screen" on my HDTV. Look in your Video Software for scaling options, and increase the scaling until you get full screen.